# How exactly are descriptor decorators called?

Tags: python, static-methods, python-decorators, python-descriptors

Given the following code that emulates a staticmethod:

```
class StaticMethod(object):
    "Emulate PyStaticMethod_Type() in Objects/funcobject.c"
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        print('getting')
        return self.f

class A:
    def func2():
        print('hello')

    func2 = StaticMethod(func2)
```

When I call:
`A.func2`
i get what i expect:

```
getting
<function __main__.A.func2>
```

When I call: `A.func2()` I get:

```
getting
hello
```

Does this mean then that whenever you call a Descriptor Decorator method Python first retrieves it from the Descriptor's `__get__` method?

If, yes, how then does the method actually get called? What exactly is happening under the hood?

Comment: What is surprising you here exactly?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean then that whenever you call a Descriptor Decorator method Python first retrieves it from the Descriptor's **get** method?

When you access an attribute on an object where its class has a class attribute that is a descriptor, the object calls `__get__` and returns the result.

A "descriptor decorator" is not really a thing, the fact that a decorator is used to set the descriptor is irrelevant to its functionality.

> If, yes, how then does the method actually get called? What exactly is happening under the hood?

If you mean the underlying function that was decorated with `staticmethod`, then the method gets called whenever you call it, the descriptor/`staticmethod` itself doesn't prescribe that, it just returns the function.